# Using flash message after redirect from form submit

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer, flash-message

I'm using Express for my website, and I've just created a contact form with nodemailer. Now I want to use a flash message to show on the contact page after the form is submitted and redirected back to the contact page.
But I'm struggling on how to use this

This is where I post the form with Nodemailer:

```
  router.get('includes/contact', function(req, res) {
  res.render('contact',{title:'Contact'});
});

//route to send the form
router.post('/contact/send', function(req, res) {

  var transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({

  service : 'Gmail',
  auth : {
    user: xxxxxxx,
    pass: xxxxxxx
  }

  });

  var mailOptions = {
    from: req.body.name + ' &lt;' + req.body.email + '&gt;',
    to: 'xxxxxx@xxx.com',
    subject:'Test subject',
    text:'Test from '+ req.body.name+' Email: '+req.body.email+'Test: '+req.body.website+'Message: '+req.body.message,
    html:'<p><ul><li>Test from Naam: '+req.body.name+'</li><li>Email: '+req.body.email+'</li><li>Test: '+req.body.website+'</li><li>Message: '+req.body.message+'</li></ul>'
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect('/#contact');
    } else {
      console.log('Message send');
      res.redirect('/#contact');
    }
  });

});
```

And my contactform:

```
.wrap
  .contact-block
    .title Contact
    form(method="post", action="contact/send")
      label Name:
        input(type="text", name="name", placeholder="Voer uw naam in")
      label Email:
        input(type="email", name="email", placeholder="Voer uw emailadres in")
      label Soort website
        select(type="select", name="website")
          option Website
          option CMS Website
          option Webshop
      label Bericht:
        textarea(name="message", placeholder="Bericht")
      button.btn-regular(type="submit") Verzenden
```

Answer (score 0):

While calling api for submitting the form on this api '/contact/send'. change code as following:

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
 if(err) {
  console.log(err);
  res.status(500).send({'status':1001});
 } else {
  console.log('Message send');
  res.status(200).send({'status':1000});
 }
});
```

This will return json as response with appropriate http status.Than according to your status in response you can show hide flash message.**No need to redirect on contact submit form.**

Comment: This did not work for me as I needed a redirect to the contact page. But I already solved it by using an Ajax call and place success function in it